# Using Offset and TextBox.Value to input between 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use an `ActiveCell.Offset` function. I am slightly confused to code using Column A as my base.

I wouldn't want to input as new row. I would want to start from number 1 instead of skipping to an empty row.

My code is as below.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A2:A2")

If TextBox1.Value = "" Then
    If MsgBox("Form is not complete. Do you want to continue?", vbQuestion+vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then
    Exit Sub
End If
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = TextBox1.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = TextBox2.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) = TextBox3.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

End Sub
```

[image: Example]

Comment: It's not clear what your goal is. Can you please [edit] your question and describe detailed step-by-step in words what you expect your procedure should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be setting a range

```
Set rng = Range("A2:A2")
```

and not using rng anywhere in the sub. In addition you seem to be basing your offset on the ActiveCell but not having a clear ActiveCell selected in the sub (you could be selecting it outside the routines of course) which leads me to suspect that this 'rng' is your desired Active cell. If this is the case then you will need to make rng the ActiveCell by activating the cell.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Have replaced ActiveCell with rng, it did work! Thank you so much!

Comment: If it was useful then you may want to accept the answer or upvote the answer as useful?

Comment: It should be mentioned that `Range("A2:A2")` dosen't make much sense because you can write just `Range("A2")`. Also you might want to specify in which sheet the range is `Worksheets("SheetName").Range("A2")` if that's always the same sheet.